# Remove the redundancy for the database insertation

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have almost same 2 methods that are used to insert in a MySQL table where the later have one parameter more namely the `PaymentRequest`. Now, the first method is used in quite a few instances in the codebase that doesn't have the 
`PaymentRequest` field and this bugs me as rest of the code is just the same.

```
public final void insertOrder(final LocalOrderImpl o, final boolean retryCommit, final boolean withExecutableNominal,
                                  final boolean withIocOrderId) throws SQLException {


        Long orderId = null;
        if (retryCommit) {
            Object[] params =
                    new Object[]{o.getUserId(), o.getLimit(), o.getNominal(), o.getState(), o.getPause_no_credit(), o.getMarketId(),
                            o.getType(), o.getExchangeId(), o.getOriginalRate(), o.getShadowOrderId(),
                            withExecutableNominal ? o.getNominal() : null, o.getIocOrderNumber()};
            orderId = insertOrderWithRetry(new InsertOrderWithRetryParams(params, withIocOrderId));
        } else if (withIocOrderId && Config.IOC_ORDER_ID_COL) {
            sqlProcessor.execute(SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER_WITH_IOC, o.getUserId(), o.getLimit(), o.getNominal(), o.getState(),
                    o.getPause_no_credit(), o.getMarketId(), o.getType(), o.getExchangeId(), o.getOriginalRate(), o.getShadowOrderId(),
                    withExecutableNominal ? o.getNominal() : null, o.getIocOrderNumber());
            orderId = readLastOrderId();
        } else {
            sqlProcessor.execute(SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER, o.getUserId(), o.getLimit(), o.getNominal(), o.getState(), o.getPause_no_credit(),
                    o.getMarketId(), o.getType(), o.getExchangeId(), o.getOriginalRate(), o.getShadowOrderId(),
                    withExecutableNominal ? o.getNominal() : null);
            orderId = readLastOrderId();
        }
        o.setOrderNumber(orderId);
        log.debug("Inserted {} order id db: {}, nominal {}, limit {}", o.isBuyOrder() ? "buy" : "sell", o.getOrderId(),
                NumberUtils.toExternal(o.getNominal()), NumberUtils.toExternal(o.getLimit()));
    }
```

This is the method that I newly wrote with the `PaymentRequest` field.

```
    /**
     * @param o
     * @param retryCommit
     * @param withExecutableNominal
     * @throws SQLException
     * @implNote stores the payment request Id in the orderbook table
     */
    public final void insertOrder(final LocalOrderImpl o, final PaymentRequest paymentRequest, final boolean retryCommit, final boolean withExecutableNominal,
                                  final boolean withIocOrderId) throws SQLException {
        Long orderId = null;
        if (retryCommit) {
            Object[] params =
                    new Object[]{paymentRequest.getId(), o.getUserId(), o.getLimit(), o.getNominal(), o.getState(), o.getPause_no_credit(), o.getMarketId(),
                            o.getType(), o.getExchangeId(), o.getOriginalRate(), o.getShadowOrderId(),
                            withExecutableNominal ? o.getNominal() : null, o.getIocOrderNumber()};
            orderId = insertOrderWithRetry(new InsertOrderWithRetryParams(params, withIocOrderId));
        } else if (withIocOrderId && Config.IOC_ORDER_ID_COL) {
            sqlProcessor.execute(SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER_WITH_IOC, paymentRequest.getId(), o.getUserId(), o.getLimit(), o.getNominal(), o.getState(),
                    o.getPause_no_credit(), o.getMarketId(), o.getType(), o.getExchangeId(), o.getOriginalRate(), o.getShadowOrderId(),
                    withExecutableNominal ? o.getNominal() : null, o.getIocOrderNumber());
            orderId = readLastOrderId();
        } else {
            sqlProcessor.execute(SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER, paymentRequest.getId(), o.getUserId(), o.getLimit(), o.getNominal(), o.getState(), o.getPause_no_credit(),
                    o.getMarketId(), o.getType(), o.getExchangeId(), o.getOriginalRate(), o.getShadowOrderId(),
                    withExecutableNominal ? o.getNominal() : null);
            orderId = readLastOrderId();
        }
        o.setOrderNumber(orderId);
        log.debug("Inserted {} order id db: {}, nominal {}, limit {}", o.isBuyOrder() ? "buy" : "sell", o.getOrderId(),
                NumberUtils.toExternal(o.getNominal()), NumberUtils.toExternal(o.getLimit()));
    }
```

The `SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER_WITH_IOC` and `SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER` has the almost same sql queries written in the `sql.yml` file. Any suggestion how to get rid of the redundency of the code?

Comment: First suggestion: clean up that code so that it is much easier to read and understand. This will help both you and us.

Comment: Do you want to use one method which will also insert the data when the Payment request mode is there and when payment Request mode is not there?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the code is not bad if you just look for what the `paymentRequest` does additionally in the second method.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee Preferably, so we can get rid of the redundancy

Comment: create two stored procedures in your database and call each stored proc for each of the repeating (but slightly different) queries.

Comment: @CowboyFarnz I don't have very advanced knowledge of the MySQL. Can you provide an example as answer? I can give the SQL for the db operation if intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see : [How to Create a Stored Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Create two stored procedures, one for 
`SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER_WITH_IOC` 
and one for `SqlQuery.INSERT_ORDER`.

Use the above link to find out how to create the stored procedure in mySql.

Then use this link [How to use JDBC Callable Statements to Exceute Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html). This will give you information on how to interact with them.

Good luck!

The Cowboy.